# CKEDITOR, When pressing enter (with br), strange characters are shown in the textarea

Tags: php, javascript, editor, ckeditor

In ckeditor (latest version), I configured the enterMode to use ENTER_BR.
But each time I press enter in the editor, it shows some weird characters ("â€‹") in front of the newly created line and I have no idea why.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "latest version" == 4.0 or 4.0.1? Your OS? OS language? Editor language? Your browser (with version)? There are too many variables to make a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well at work, on a legacy application that had been fitted with ckeditor (4.0, I believe).

For us, it was an issue with the charset attribute on the script tag in html. They had been set to ISO-8859-1:

```
<script src="somejsfile.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
```

Either removing the charset attribute or setting it to UTF-8 resolves this problem for us.